# Insert into edge table in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, graph, sql-server-2017

Currently I'm trying to learn the graph database features of SQL Server 2017, and for this purpose I am trying to load a set of current data into a set of node and edge tables.

I have not had issues loading into node tables from a `SELECT` query. But I am encountering trouble when trying to load data into my edges table.

I have a table named kontomappingDetaljeret, that contains kontoNummer and refNr

I also have node tables containing these features as nodes. I am trying to map the relationship between the kontoNummer and refNr columns.

So far I have this query that does not execute

```
INSERT INTO brugtIRef 
VALUES 
    ((SELECT $node_id FROM o90Konto WHERE kontoNummer = konti.konto),
     (SELECT $node_id FROM refNummer WHERE refNr = konti.refNr))
FROM
    KontomappingDetaljeret konti
INNER JOIN
    o90Konto ON konti.konto = o90Konto.kontoNummer
INNER JOIN
    refNummer ON konti.refNr = refNummer.refNr
```

EDIT

WHEN Running the following query I get this result

```
SELECT TOP (10)
    (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.o90Konto WHERE kontoNummer = konti.konto) AS KontoNr,
    (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.refNummer WHERE refNr = konti.refNr) AS refNr

FROM
    KontomappingDetaljeret konti

INNER JOIN
    dbo.o90Konto
ON 
    konti.konto = o90Konto.kontoNummer

INNER JOIN
    dbo.refNummer
ON 
    konti.refNr = refNummer.refNr
```

Results in

```
KontoNr refNr
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":180657}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":0}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":211723}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":1}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":216400}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":2}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":205844}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":3}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":388939}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":4}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":536204}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":5}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":130331}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":6}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":83983}    {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":7}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":344522}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":7}
{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"o90Konto","id":523743}   {"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"refNummer","id":7}
```

I just need some way to insert this result into the edges table

Comment: You say "I have this query that does not execute". Are you getting any errors? Can you post them? Your second query also seems to indicate some of your tables are in different databases and/or instances, is this the case?

Comment: sorry about that When I say it does not execute, this is because it is not a correct syntaxt I get the error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. And yes I pull data frm one server (MS SQL Server 2016) to a server on my local pc (MS SQL Server 2017)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out

```
INSERT INTO 
    dbo.brugtIRef
    SELECT 
        (SELECT DISTINCT $node_id FROM o90Konto WHERE kontoNummer = konti.konto) AS KontoNr,
        (SELECT DISTINCT $node_id FROM refNummer WHERE refNr = konti.refNr) AS refNr

    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT konto, refNr FROM KontomappingDetaljeret) konti

    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM o90Konto) o90Konto
    ON 
        konti.konto = o90Konto.kontoNummer

    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM refNummer) refNummer 
    ON 
        konti.refNr = refNummer.refNr
```

I can now run queries against this graph